# How to replace all instances of a character

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to implement lazy loading on images on an ASP.NET page. The problem is that my ASP.NET control generates the images like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="imagePath" class="lazy" height="100px"  data-original='<%#Utilities.GetImageUrl(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FullImagePath").ToString(), true)%>' src="http://placehold.it/100x100" runat="server" AlternateText='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name")%>' />
```

...and my data-original is rendered like `"~/Content/Products/foo.jpg"` and lazy loading fails because of the ~ character.

I really don't know how to program in C#, so I am relying on JS to remove each instance of the ~ character. How can I achieve this in js or jquery? I've tried:

```
$(".lazy").each(function(i){
    var url=$(this).attr("data-original");
    url.replace("~","");
    $(this).attr("data-original",url);

});
```

...with no luck.
Please help.

Comment: Would it not be better to change your `GetImageUrl` function to return an absolute path instead?

Comment: It would, except that i do not have access to the CodeBehind to do that and, as I mentioned, I don't know C#... I'm doing a front end redesign of an ASP.net e-commerce site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
url=url.replace("~","");
$(this).attr("data-original",url);
```

if you want to remove 1st char `~`

```
url = url.slice(1,url.length); 
$(this).attr("data-original",url);
```

Replace All Instances

```
  var re = new RegExp('~', 'g');
  url = url.replace(re, '');
  $(this).attr("data-original",url);
```

Comment: If it's not to much... I also have a "live search box" that loads the listings from this apsx page via ajax .load() method. 
The problem is lazy load won't work in the results container. I've tried every setting but still no luck. The result page from witch I load the results container has lazy load implemented and works (thanks to you), but in my ajax loaded container the images just don't replace.